# Problems with taylor series

Tags: matlab, logarithm, exponential, taylor-series

I'm trying to obtain an array with the results of a **Taylor series**.

The `f(a)` functions i'm experimenting with are the exponential and logarithmic functions.

**Here is the code:**

```
clear, clc, clf,

x = [1:5];
a = 2;


for k = 0:4
    P1(k+1) = (diff(exp(a), a, k+1) / factorial(k)) * (x(k+1) - a)^k;
    P2(k+1) = (diff(log(a), a, k+1) / factorial(k)) * (x(k+1) - a)^k;
end

tab = [x' P1' P2'];

figure(1),clf
plot(x, P1, 'ro--');
hold on
plot(x, P2, 'b*:');
```

I'm getting the following **error**:

```
Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in atv2 (line 8)
    P1(k+1) = (diff(exp(a), a, k+1) / factorial(k)) * (x(k+1) - a)^k;
```

I would appreciate it if you guys could help me with the code.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html